# In generics how can we set one type exactly similar to another?

Tags: generics, c#-4.0

What is wrong

```
public class GameInitializatorAdaptee<u> : CollectionInitializationAdapter<Game, v> where v:u
```

Error: The type or namespace name 'v' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can i do it?

Idea is v should be equal to u..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
public class GameInitializatorAdaptee<u> : 
  CollectionInitializationAdapter<Game, u>
```

"u" is the placeholder for your generic type.